# No me reconoce una función de una clase en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, clase, retorno

```
class Video():
def __init__(self, titulo, duracion, lanzamiento): 
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.duracion = duracion
    self.lanzamiento = lanzamiento 
    print('Se creo el video', self.titulo)
def __str__(self):
    return (f"{self.titulo} publicado en {self.lanzamiento} con una duracion de {self.duracion} minutos")
def __del__(self):
    return (f"Se elimino el video {self.titulo}")
```

Solo me ejecuta estas instrucciones:

c=Video('The Avengers', 143, 2012)

d=Video('Thepanther', 145, 2022)

print (str(c),"\n",str(d))

La funcion **del** cuando la voy a utilizar no me retorna lo indicado, y si intento otro nombre para ella no lo reconoce. Deberia aparecerme como parte de la clase pero no lo hace.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que este ejemplo es del curso de udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/python-3-curso-completo-de-cero-a-experto/learn/lecture/22958806#content

Lo tengo tal cual al video de la lección (video 49, sesión 7) y la verdad no entiendo que tengo que modificar, soy principiante.

Comment: El error es simple, el método `__del__` no retorna nada, solo reemplaza el `return` por un `print`

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que llamar a la función `print` en vez de usar un `return`:

```py
class Video():
    def __init__(self, titulo, duracion, lanzamiento): 
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.duracion = duracion
        self.lanzamiento = lanzamiento 
        print('Se creo el video', self.titulo)
    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.titulo} publicado en {self.lanzamiento} con una duracion de {self.duracion} minutos")
    def __del__(self):
        print(f"Se elimino el video {self.titulo}")
```

Con esto ya verías cuándo se invoca:

```py
d=Video('Thepanther', 145, 2022)
del d
Se elimino el video Thepanther
```

Comment: Muchas gracias:)

Comment: Amigo Joan una preguntica, sabe alguna forma de hacer que el ,ensaje de se elimino el video x no se muestre cada vez que se compila aun cuando no se llame a la funcion del?

Comment: A qué te refieres con "cada vez que se compila"?

Comment: Es que en la terminal siempre se me ejecutaba la cadena "se elimino el video tal" cada vez que se creaba un video...Sin embargo ya le encontre una solucion

Answer (score -1):

Es posible que estés teniendo problemas al usar el método **del** de la clase Video. Este método mágico se llama automáticamente cuando se elimina una instancia de la clase (por ejemplo, cuando se ejecuta del video). Sin embargo, el método no debe tener ningún valor de retorno, ya que su función es simplemente realizar una acción (en este caso, imprimir un mensaje).

Para solucionar este problema, simplemente elimina la línea return (f"Se eliminó el video {self.titulo}") del método **del** y reemplázala con print(f"Se eliminó el video {self.titulo}").

Ejemplo de uso:

```
class Video():
    def __init__(self, titulo, duracion, lanzamiento): 
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.duracion = duracion
        self.lanzamiento = lanzamiento 
        print('Se creó el video', self.titulo)
    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.titulo} publicado en {self.lanzamiento} con una duración de {self.duracion} minutos")
    def __del__(self):
        print(f"Se eliminó el video {self.titulo}")

c = Video('The Avengers', 143, 2012)
d = Video('The Panther', 145, 2022)
print(str(c), "\n", str(d))
del c
```

Espero que esto solucione tu problema. Si tienes alguna pregunta o necesitas más detalles, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Tu respuesta sería más valiosa si **mostraras** lo que sugieres..